# How to download newly created HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html

I create an HTML file with `document.implementation.createHTMLDocument()` function. Like so:

```
 var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("My New Document");
```

And I want to download this newly create HTML document. I tried this:

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = doc;
link.download = 'newDoc.html';
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
document.body.removeChild(link);
```

But doesn't work. It redirects me to `myDomain.com/[object HTMLDocument]`. How can I download this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Couple of stages.

1. Place the HTML of the document into a blob,.
2. Convert blob into a blob url
3. Create a link to download this url

Example below..

```js
const bt = document.querySelector('button');
bt.addEventListener('click', () => {
  //lets create some document
  const doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("My New Document");
  const hello = doc.createElement('p');
  hello.innerText = 'Hello';
  doc.body.appendChild(hello);
  
  //now get it's contents and place into a blob
  const blob = new Blob([doc.documentElement.innerHTML], {
    type: 'text/html'
   });
   
  //now convert to url
  const docUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob); 
  
  //were done, lets create a href to this and download
  const aclick = document.createElement('a');
  aclick.href = docUrl;
  aclick.download = 'download.html';
  aclick.click();
  
  //tidy up
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(docUrl);
});
```

```html
<p>Click button below to download some HTML</p>

<button>download</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot append the `filename` in `URL`, Because the `HTML File` that you created using  `createHTMLDocument()` **is not a actual HTML file** and Not available in your server, It's a **Javascript HTMLDocument Object**.

You can use [Data URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs), as follows, [Complete Tutorial Here..](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/189/how-to-create-a-file-and-generate-a-download-with-javascript-in-the-browser-without-a-server)

```js
function download(filename, text) {
  var element = document.createElement('a');
  element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
  element.setAttribute('download', filename);

  element.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(element);

  element.click();

  document.body.removeChild(element);
}

// Start file download.
download("newDoc.html","<html><head><title>Hello</title></head><body>Hello World!</body></html>");
```

> **NOTE: The function `encodeURIComponent()` will not affect the HTML after download.**

Comment: Just temporarily, When you open and see the downloaded html file, It will have actual content.

Comment: Banujan, thank you for your answer. But, I cannot type html tags and elements like you did in your answer, I need to append them to the html file. So, that's why I will accept the other answer.

Comment: Yes, forget that the href will automatically get a decode URI.  But there are other issues too,.  If the document is large the limits of URL length can kick in.  There is also the overhead eg.  '' that would normally be 4 bytes, is now -> `%F0%9F%98%8A` twelve bytes.  But for small files this should be Ok..

Answer (score 0):

```js
function download(filename, text) {
  var element = document.createElement('a');
  element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
  element.setAttribute('download', filename);

  element.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(element);

  element.click();

  document.body.removeChild(element);
}


// Start file download.
function myFunction(){
  let html = document.getElementById("textarea").value;;
  download("hello.html", html); 
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea" placeholder="Type your HTML here..."><h1>WORKING?????</h1></textarea>

<button onclick="myFunction()">GET FILE</button>
```